# Tesla coil arc in air - where is it going?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

here is a picture of a Tesla coil with a discharge that seemingly terminates in the air[image: Tesla coil with a discharge that seemingly terminates in the air].

What completes the circuit at the end of the streamers?

Answer (score 10):

What the picture shows is a [corona discharge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=corona%20discharge) ([see also Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge)).

It isn't a circuit in the usual sense of the word. It happens because the voltage is so high that it raises the electron energy to above the work function and the electrons just leak off. In effect the coil is charging the air around it. The charge will end up on the furniture, walls, floor, and indeed you if you're in the vicinity.

Comment: I agree. It's more like charging a capacitor  (the room). From  my experience,  after running my coil I've noticed a residual charge in the secondary coil after disconnecting and dismantling. I'm guessing this is a net positive charge left after the elections have flown off.

Comment: Since a tesla coil is AC, doesn't a decent fraction of the charge end up back on the toroid? Genuine question, I know it might not be true because the dynamics aren't exactly symmetrical, but my instinct says it's mostly true.